# «Пушкинский платан». С большой буквы?

Tags: выбор-слов

«Пушкинский платан». Есть в Крыму платан, где устраивают чтения произведений Пушкина. С большой или маленькой буквы писать в данном случае «П/пушкинский».

Comment: или платан посадил Пушкин..как-то так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В текстах встречаются разные варианты написания, все они нормативны.

1) **Нарицательное сочетание** (связанный с именем Пушкина)

Около дома Ришелье сохранился кипарис, о котором поэт писал в письме Антону Дельвигу, и **пушкинский платан**, посаженный в 1838 году, в первую годовщину смерти поэта.

2) **Нарицательное сочетание,** но его условность обозначена кавычками

В придачу к кипарису показывают «пушкинский платан», но есть данные, что это дерево посажено уже в 1930-е годы.

3) **Имя собственное в двух вариантах** (без кавычек и с кавычками), обычно кавычки отсутствуют в заголовках.

Одно из них «Пушкинский платан», раскинувший свои могучие ветви рядом с домом , где в августе-сентябре 1820 года жил А.Пушкин.

Пушкинский платан. Растет в Гурзуфе, в парке у Дома-музея Пушкина, ул. Набережная, 3. Посажен И.И.Фундуклеем в год смерти поэта в 1838 г, Обхват дерева около 5 м., высота 30 м,. возраст 150 лет.